# Hiding page names in the browser

Tags: html, browser

When we launch a website, we usually see webpage name (`menu.php` or `admin.aspx`) but I would like to hide that name and show only virtual path or just website name. I don't want it for the first page because I did that with `default.aspx` but I want to implement it for the whole website.

Showing `www.abcd.com/faq/` instead of `www.abcd.com/faq/faq.html`

Note: My code is not `MVC` code and server is Apache.

Comment: What web server are you using?  This is doable with Apache and probably with other web server software as well.

Comment: It depends on the server, is it Apache? IIS?

Comment: @jasper Xampp isn't a server. So you are using apache.

Comment: you *could* also create a folder for every webpage, and then call the file `index.php` or whatever extension you're using. So, instead of `menu.php` you make an `index.php` in the `menu` folder. That way, you can access it from `/menu/`. This will make the slash at the end mandatory though.

Comment: Downvote for what research question ?? Its not research question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .htaccess to rewrite the URL. Millions of tutorials are out there for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is achieved using (for xampp, wamp, lamp or any other apache powered webserver setup) htaccess rewriterules. The rules take the URL and break it into parts that can be modified or used as variables to feed other pages - whilst still keeping the URL you typed. Neat huh!

Answer (score 1):

> Showing www.abcd.com/faq/ instead of www.abcd.com/faq/faq.html

call the file placed into the folder `faq` simply `index.html` (not `faq.html`) and then `www.abcd.com/faq/`
will display the page without the filename. (Make sure, you have defined `index.html` as a valid Directory index.)

There are more options with using `mod_rewrite` etc - but since you seem to use a prety static directory based navigation layout, that would be the easiest way.